# Liberty - No Extension Processor found for handling JSPs

Tags: configuration, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

In a REST microservice application, [one can replicate it using one of the getting start with open liberty sample applications](https://openliberty.io/guides/getting-started.html), if you add a JSP page you get a http 403 (forbiden) error and in the warning message: No Extension Processor found for handling JSPs.

Googling about error in liberty and the warning message yeil no results, (more percisely 4 results not regarding liberty), so I aspire to create usefull result with this question/answer.

Comment: If you are using REST example and not enabling correct features then what you expect? Googling "openliberty jsp" - gives you feature to enable - https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/jsp-2.2.html

Comment: Hello Gas, bear in mind that the 403 (forbiden) error and the warning did not point to your insitefull search suggestion. At the time I did not had in mind that one could  control the pieces of the runtime environment that are loaded into a particular server with features this way, and I am pretty sure that there are more out there that still do not know, it would be nice if liberty had logged a message more explicit about a likely missing configuration to enable JSP feature...

Answer (score 1):

The Liberty server configuration file does not has JSP enabled, need to explicitily enable it [adding `<feature>pages-3.1</feature>` inside featureManager element in server.xml](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/pages-3.1.html), file location src\main\liberty\config\server.xml

One can go wider and add the `<feature>webProfile-10.0</feature>` to inclue the usual API's used in a traditional web application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error message. For me, the solution was to download:
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/openliberty/runtime/release/2021-01-13_1459 /openliberty-javaee8-21.0.0.1.zip 
because the issue occurred on openliberty-21.0.0.1.zip, it seems to be a corrupted installer.